# Using NanoHTTPD in Android

Tags: android, file, http, nanohttpd

I am trying to use NanoHTTP to serve up an HTML file. However, NanoHTTP is relatively un-documented, and I am new to Android. My question is, where do I store the html file, and how specifically can I serve it up using NanoHTTP.

Comment: Unless this is some existing Android port of NanoHTTPD, you have some work ahead of you, not something I would recommend for somebody "new to Android". If it *is* some existing Android port of NanoHTTPD, the authors of that port hopefully provided some means for you to specify the document root via a `File`.

Comment: well, I am new to Android, but I am not new to Java or networking. All I need is a little push in the right direction.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A late answer but may be useful to others.

Here is a simple hello Web Server, not exactly what you ask, but you can continue from here. The following program supposes you have a `www` directory in the root of the SD Card and a file `index.html` inside.

Main activity `Httpd.java`:

```
package com.inforscience.web;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Httpd extends Activity
{
    private WebServer server;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        server = new WebServer();
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            Log.w("Httpd", "The server could not start.");
        }
        Log.w("Httpd", "Web server initialized.");
    }


    // DON'T FORGET to stop the server
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (server != null)
            server.stop();
    }

    private class WebServer extends NanoHTTPD {

        public WebServer()
        {
            super(8080);
        }

        @Override
        public Response serve(String uri, Method method, 
                              Map<String, String> header,
                              Map<String, String> parameters,
                              Map<String, String> files) {
            String answer = "";
            try {
                // Open file from SD Card
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                FileReader index = new FileReader(root.getAbsolutePath() +
                        "/www/index.html");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(index);
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer += line;
                }
                reader.close();

            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                Log.w("Httpd", ioe.toString());
            }


            return new NanoHTTPD.Response(answer);
        }
    }

}
```

Obviously the `NanoHTTPD` class must be in the same package.

You need to grant internet permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and read external storage permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**EDIT:** To access the server open you web browser with the IP of your device, e.g. `192.168.1.20:8080`.

**NOTES:**

- Tested in Android 2.3
- The use of port 80 is restricted to the root user(http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg47377.html).

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I should have added my own code once I figured it out (which took a while).

Comment: Adding my thanks.  Seriously, very helpful.  This is the first nanohttpd example I've found that actually works with the current nanohttpd.  My process: Create a new Android application project, paste in your main activity (changing the package name and activity name to match my project), copy in the NanoHTTPD.java file (from nanohttpd-master/core/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/ in the current https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd download), add the INTERNET permission, create the www/index.html file, and that was it.  Boom.  Ran the app on my Note II and viewed the webpage from my PC.  Works!

Comment: You are welcome. I used a server for a college project(https://bitbucket.org/rendon/smsserver) and NanoHTTPD did the work so well.

Comment: @AndrewCottrell "and viewed the webpage from my PC. Works" How do you communicate between webpage and android activity?

Comment: Thanks, works on Lollipop. I only had to change R.layout.main to R.layout.activity_main

Comment: Can you comment on how to use the SSL support in NanoHTTPD?  The docs claim it's in a separate branch I cannot find, but I found a message exchange suggesting it has been merged into the master branch already.

Comment: @Michael I'd like to, but it's been a long time since I used NanoHTTPD, I didn't use SSL in my application, so I don't know about the subject :(.

Comment: You should integrate the server in a `Service` and not in an `Activity`. Otherwise you have to deal with closed connections on device rotation etc.

Comment: if nanohttpd has a file server, why are you opening the string and reading/serving it yourself? Your version also has a huge memory overhead for large files while the native natnohttpd version advertises zero memory overhead.

Comment: @MartinKonecny I shared this for didactic purposes, it's basically a Hello World, not intended to run in production :).

Comment: Can I run this server as a part of an instrumented test?

Comment: @bashan Unfortunately, I couldn't tell.

Comment: @AndrewCottrell where did you put the nanohttpd.java file?

Comment: @artkoenig would you happen to have an example of it in a service?

Answer (score 10):

Pretty good source code can be found here:
https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye

Chceck assets folder where html and JavaScript files are stored
https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye/tree/master/assets

TeaServer - server implementation
https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye/blob/master/src/teaonly/droideye/TeaServer.java

MainActivity - server initialization
https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye/blob/master/src/teaonly/droideye/MainActivity.java

Comment: This does not work on Android 3 and above, as you cannot do Networking from a UI thread

Comment: This does work on Android 3+ and serves images/scripts/etc out of the box. I'd been searching for something that worked for a couple of days. Their implementation handles MIME types without having to specify manually as well. Thank you so much for this info :)

Answer (score 9):

Updated `WebServer` class (see rendon's reply) that works with current NanoHTTPD version:

```java
private class WebServer extends NanoHTTPD {

    public WebServer() {
        super(8080);
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
        String answer = "";
        try {
            // Open file from SD Card
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            FileReader index = new FileReader(root.getAbsolutePath() +
                    "/www/index.html");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(index);
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                answer += line;
            }
            reader.close();

        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            Log.w("Httpd", ioe.toString());
        }

        return newFixedLengthResponse(answer);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at how I serve HTML files and other type of files too.
I have a AndroidWebServer class which extends the Nanohttpd class.
This is my response method -->

```
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    String uri=session.getUri();
    String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1>\n";

    File [] arrayfile;

    int i=0;

    try{
        session.parseBody(new HashMap<String, String>());
    }catch (ResponseException | IOException r){
        r.printStackTrace();
    }


    Map<String, String> parms = session.getParms();
    if (parms.get("username") == null) {
        msg += "<form action='?' method='get'>\n  <p>Your name: <input type='text' name='username'></p>\n" + "</form>\n";
    } else {
        msg += "<p>Hello, " + parms.get("username") + "!</p>";
    }
    msg += "<br><br><a href='/Open_rap'>Open Image of Lionel Messi</a><br><br>";
    msg += "<br><br><a href='/files'>Browse Files</a><br><br>";
    msg += "<br><br><a href='/getmethod'>GET METHOD OPERATION</a><br><br>";
    msg += "<br><br><a href='/postmethod'>POST METHOD OPERATION</a><br><br>";
    msg += "<br><br><a href='/jquery'>JQUERY OPERATION</a><br><br>";
    if(uri.equals("/hello")){
            String response="Hello World";
            return  newFixedLengthResponse(response);
    }
    else if(uri.equals("/getmethod")){
        String html="<html><head><h1>Welcome to the Form</h1><head/><body>";

        if(parms.get("name")==null){
            html +="<form action='' method='get'> \n " +
                    "<p>Enter Your Name:</p> <input type='text' name='name'>" +
                    "</form>" +
                    "</body>";
        }
        else{
            html +="<p>Hello Mr. "+ parms.get("name") +"</p>"+
                    "</body> ";
        }

        html +="</html>";
        return newFixedLengthResponse(html);

    }
    else if(uri.equals("/postmethod")){
        String html="<html><head><h1>Welcome to the Form</h1><head/><body>";
        Map<String, String> files = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Method method = session.getMethod();
        String postParameter="";


        html +="<form action='' method='post'> \n " +
                "<p>Enter Your Name:</p> <input type='text' name='name'>" +
                "</form>";

        if (Method.POST.equals(method) || Method.PUT.equals(method)) {
            try {
                session.parseBody(files);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                try {
                   // return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.INTERNAL_ERROR, MIME_PLAINTEXT, "SERVER INTERNAL ERROR: IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
                }
            } catch (ResponseException re) {
                try {
                   // return newFixedLengthResponse(re.getStatus(), MIME_PLAINTEXT, re.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Exception", re.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        html +="</body></html>";
        String postBody = session.getQueryParameterString();
        postParameter = session.getParms().get("name");
        Log.d("Postbody",postBody+"\n"+postParameter);
        if(postParameter!=null){
            String html1="<html><head><h1>"+ postParameter +"</h1><head></html>";
            return newFixedLengthResponse(html1);
        }
        return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.OK,"text/html",html);
    }

    else if(uri.equals("/Open_rap")){

        File root= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        File file = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/www/messi.jpg");
        Log.d("Path",root.getAbsolutePath());
        try{
            if(file.exists())
            {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            }
            else
                Log.d("FOF :", "File Not exists:");
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.OK,"image/jpeg",fis, file.length() );
    }
  else {
        return newFixedLengthResponse(msg + "</body></html>\n");
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have implemented GET and POST method. You can find each in this part of the code `uri.equals("/getmethod")` and `uri.equals("/getmethod")`.
Also, you can see the part --> `uri.equals("/openrap")`  , here I am serving a JPG file to the client's browser and the image is present in the internal directory at `/www/` folder.
Ping me if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...
Create 2 packages(activity, util), only for organization
In activity create the class MainActivity.java in util create the class AndroidWebServer.java

```
package awserverfatepi.com.activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import awserverfatepi.com.R;
import awserverfatepi.com.util.AndroidWebServer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 8080;

    private AndroidWebServer androidWebServer;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiverNetworkState;
    private static boolean isStarted = false;

    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private EditText editTextPort;
    private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButtonOnOff;
    private View textViewMessage;
    private TextView textViewIpAccess;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initGui();
        setIpAccess();
        floatingActionButtonOnOff = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonOnOff);
        floatingActionButtonOnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isConnectedInWifi()) {
                    if (!isStarted && startAndroidWebServer()) {
                        isStarted = true;
                        textViewMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        floatingActionButtonOnOff.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(MainActivity.this,
                                R.color.colorGreen));
                        editTextPort.setEnabled(false);
                    } else if (stopAndroidWebServer()) {
                        isStarted = false;
                        textViewMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        floatingActionButtonOnOff.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(MainActivity.this,
                                R.color.colorRed));
                        editTextPort.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, getString(R.string.wifi_message), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        initBroadcastReceiverNetworkStateChanged();
    }

    private void initGui() {
        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
        editTextPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPort);
        textViewMessage = findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);
        textViewIpAccess = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewIpAccess);
    }

    private boolean startAndroidWebServer() {
        if (!isStarted) {
            int port = getPortFromEditText();
            try {
                if (port == 0) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                androidWebServer = new AndroidWebServer(port);
                androidWebServer.start();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "A porta " + port + " não está funcionando, por favor altere para outra no intervalo" +
                        " entre 1000 e 9999.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean stopAndroidWebServer() {
        if (isStarted && androidWebServer != null) {
            androidWebServer.stop();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void setIpAccess() {
        textViewIpAccess.setText(getIpAccess());
    }

    private void initBroadcastReceiverNetworkStateChanged() {
        final IntentFilter filters = new IntentFilter();
        filters.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
        filters.addAction("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE");
        broadcastReceiverNetworkState = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                setIpAccess();
            }
        };
        super.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverNetworkState, filters);
    }

    private String getIpAccess() {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        int ipAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
        final String formatedIpAddress = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),
                (ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
        return "http://" + formatedIpAddress + ":";
    }

    private int getPortFromEditText() {
        String valueEditText = editTextPort.getText().toString();
        return (valueEditText.length() > 0) ? Integer.parseInt(valueEditText) : DEFAULT_PORT;
    }

    public boolean isConnectedInWifi() {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()
                && wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() && networkInfo.getTypeName().equals("WIFI")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent evt) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (isStarted) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.warning)
                        .setMessage(R.string.dialog_exit_message)
                        .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(android.R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(android.R.string.cancel), null)
                        .show();
            } else {
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopAndroidWebServer();
        isStarted = false;
        if (broadcastReceiverNetworkState != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiverNetworkState);
        }
    }

}
```

In the AndroidWebserver.java

```
package awserverfatepi.com.util;
import java.util.Map;
import fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD;

public class AndroidWebServer extends NanoHTTPD {

    public AndroidWebServer(int port) {
        super(port);
    }

    public AndroidWebServer(String hostname, int port) {
        super(hostname, port);
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
        String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1>\n";
        Map<String, String> parms = session.getParms();
        if (parms.get("username") == null) {
            msg += "<form action='?' method='get'>\n  <p>Seu nome: <input type='text' name='username'></p>\n" + "</form>\n";
        } else {
            msg += "<p>Hello, " + parms.get("username") + "!</p>";
        }
        return newFixedLengthResponse( msg + "</body></html>\n" );
    }
}
```

Don't forget Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And last

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/header" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewIpAccess"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="http://000.000.000.000:"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPort"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="8080"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:maxLength="4"
                    android:text="8080"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/message"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButtonOnOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/on_btn"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorRed" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This static server serves HTML file, does routing and works for React apps as well. You can run React app by using Andorid WebView. Create main/assets/index.html or copy React build folder into main/assets/ directory. Add url http://localhost:8080 to your WebView or browser.

```
package com.example.httpd;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.FileNameMap;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Random;

import fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private HttpServer server;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        server = new HttpServer();
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.d(TAG, "The server could not start.");
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Web server initialized.");
    }

    // DON'T FORGET to stop the server
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (server != null)
            server.stop();
    }

    private class HttpServer extends NanoHTTPD {

        public static final String
                MIME_PLAINTEXT = "text/plain",
                MIME_HTML = "text/html",
                MIME_JS = "application/javascript",
                MIME_CSS = "text/css",
                MIME_PNG = "image/png",
                MIME_DEFAULT_BINARY = "application/octet-stream",
                MIME_XML = "text/xml";

        private static final int PORT = 8080;
        private static final String TAG = "HttpServer";
        private AssetManager assetManager;
        public HttpServer() {
            super(PORT);
        }

        @Override
        public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
            assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream;
            Response response = newChunkedResponse(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST, MIME_PLAINTEXT, null);
            String uri = session.getUri();

            try {
                if (session.getMethod() == Method.GET && uri != null) {
                    if (uri.contains(".js")) {
                        inputStream = assetManager.open(uri.substring(1));
                        return newChunkedResponse(Response.Status.OK, MIME_JS, inputStream);
                    } else if (uri.contains(".css")) {
                        inputStream = assetManager.open(uri.substring(1));
                        return newChunkedResponse(Response.Status.OK, MIME_CSS, inputStream);
                    } else if (uri.contains(".png")) {
                        inputStream = assetManager.open(uri.substring(1));
                        return newChunkedResponse(Response.Status.OK, MIME_PNG, inputStream);
                    } else if (uri.contains("/mnt/sdcard")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "request for media on sdCard " + uri);
                        File file = new File(uri);
                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                        FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
                        String contentType = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(uri);
                        Response streamResponse = newChunkedResponse(Response.Status.OK, contentType, fileInputStream);
                        Random random = new Random();
                        String hexString = Integer.toHexString(random.nextInt());
                        streamResponse.addHeader("ETag", hexString);
                        streamResponse.addHeader("Connection", "Keep-alive");
                        return streamResponse;
                    } else {
                        inputStream = assetManager.open("index.html");
                        return newChunkedResponse(Response.Status.OK, MIME_HTML, inputStream);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.3.1'
    ...
}
```

res/values/strings.html

```
<resources>
    <string name="http_index">index.html</string>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```