# Android web server nanohttpd - cannot connect from browser on same device

Tags: android, webserver, localhost, nanohttpd

I have attempted to set up a simple web server on Android using the nanohttpd demo application without modification. The Android devices that I am using are running Android 4.0.3.

I am able to access the web server from other devices, but I am unable to connect to the web server from a browser (Firefox, Chrome, and the native Android browser) on the same Android device that the web server is running.

I have tried a variety of addresses and port combinations without success (localhost, 127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, the actual assigned IP address, port 8080, 8082). I have also tried having the nanohttpd application bind directly to 127.0.0.1, without success either. I have verified that I can ‘ping’ the addresses using a terminal application on the Android device, so it looks like the network connectivity is fine.

Is there a restriction on Android that will prevent a browser from connecting to the local web server instance, and if so, is there a configuration setting or permission that needs to be modified to allow this to work?

Comment: Strange story. That should just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a bunch of trial and error, I believe that I have a handle on what is happening. When I switch from the web server application to the browser to try the request, the web server application is suspended and therefore will not accept the connection. I had assumed that the applications were running in the background, but apparently that is not the case.

I'll explore how to run the web server as a background service and see where that takes me.

After embedding the nanohttpd web server inside an Android service, all is working as I had originally intended.

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to grant internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2) Also the port 80 will not be available without root.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309256/using-nanohttpd-in-android) for more information.

3) Disable any VPN or proxy app or data compression on your device

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I have granted INTERNET permission in the manifest, and I am using port 8080 by default. All works fine when I access the web server from another device, like my desktop PC. I just cannot access the web server from the same device.

Comment: What do you get when you try from the device ? A 404?
Also can you post your code please?

Comment: I am using the sample code without modification from here, before I extend it with my own implementation: https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/HelloServer.java. The TCP connection to the web server is never established, and I get a "Unable to connect" message on the browser

Comment: Do you perhaps have a proxy app or vpn on your device? What manufacturer/device are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Change the request url to **http://localhost:port** or if you want to use IP address for localhost on emulator you can use the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking).