# How to clear blank view in WebView in android?

Tags: android, webview

right now i am working with webview, i reffered many codes regarding this but still i can't figure why i am not able to get the view in my device. I went through lot of examples, still no use, can you guys help to clear this issue. Thanks in advance, below is my code. I am loading file in WebView from the local SD card in device.

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new DemoJavaScriptInterface(), "demo");
    webView.loadUrl(filePath);

final class DemoJavaScriptInterface {
    DemoJavaScriptInterface() {
    }

    public void clickOnAndroid() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:wave()");
            }
        });

    }
}

 final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
            result.confirm();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You explain that something is not working, but I'm not sure I get what actually is the problem here... What is the exact "issue"?

Comment: well, i am getting blank page instead of documents in webview.

Comment: Are you trying to load html/css content from SD card ? Maybe you should start a webserver on the device to do this (maybe use NanoHTTP)

Comment: i am trying with each and every type of files like .pdf, .ppt, .xlsx,.doc is it possbile in webview

Comment: @HugoG can you tell me clearly what should i do? or suppose any link related to your answer.

Comment: Refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749569/load-local-html-file-into-webview
Or this one : https://www.google.fr/search?q=load+local+file+in+webview+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=OZORVNANg6w679uBqAw

Comment: i will get back once after checking with your answers thanks man

Comment: is the file you want to show a static HTML page? is filePath a valid path to your file? try to print it and see if it's not pointing to a non-existing file or similar...

Comment: i think its for only loading Html files into webview and from asset folder.

Comment: @albemala filePath is a valid path. No i don't want to show a static HTML page.

Comment: so, as @HugoG said, you should probably use a webserver to access you web page

Comment: plz mark any answer as solved or answer your own question and close the subject

Comment: i still didn't get my answer, well once i find it i will surely put it as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show not static page with html/css/js, you have to use a local webserver (like NanoHTTPD) on the device to host your files.

For more information about using NanoHTTPD, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309256/using-nanohttpd-in-android). One this done, juste load the local url corresponding to the local server on your webView.