# File transfer from android mobile to android tv

Tags: android, android-tv

Wanna create an app for file transfer from android mobile to android tv like this [Send files to tv](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yablio.sendfilestotv&hl=en_IN&gl=US).Using wifi p2p file transfer or any other technic should i use to achieve this? If i use wifi p2p i should enable location permission.But [Send files to tv](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yablio.sendfilestotv&hl=en_IN&gl=US) not asking location permission. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Wifi p2p you can combine it with [NanoHttpD](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) server to serve your file to the TV Device over wifi. NanoHttpD is a very small web server which can be used to serve both Rest API's which can then be called by the application embedded on the TV or you can stream files using it.

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309256/using-nanohttpd-in-android) answer on how to use it on Android.